# Sanitize user-inputted url in python?

Tags: python, security, sanitization

Is there a reputable library for this? I have read that replacing dangerous characters with regex is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try `urllib.parse.urlparse()` The documentation for Python3 can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html .

Comment: Doesn't that just make it safe to put in html href? The link itself could still be dangerous, no?

Comment: Yeah, try this: https://pypi.org/project/is-safe-url/